# No alive nodes found in your cluster Laravel Docker elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I'm trying to use elasticsearch for my search function of my page using laravel and docker. As I've do the test run, it returns this error:

> exception: "Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException"
>   file: "/var/www/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php"
>
> line: 53
>
> message: "No alive nodes found in your cluster"

I'm following the instructions stated in [GitHub](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent). I have already added `"elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master"` in my `composer.json` file and added `Elasticquent\ElasticquentServiceProvider::class,` and `'Elasticsearch' => Elasticquent\ElasticquentElasticsearchFacade::class,` as well in my `app.php` file.

This is how my model looks like:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;

class Item extends Model
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    /**
     * cast dates
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    /**
     * The elasticsearch settings.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $indexSettings = [
        'analysis' => [
            'char_filter' => [
                'replace' => [
                    'type' => 'mapping',
                    'mappings' => [
                        '&=> and '
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'filter' => [
                'word_delimiter' => [
                    'type' => 'word_delimiter',
                    'split_on_numerics' => false,
                    'split_on_case_change' => true,
                    'generate_word_parts' => true,
                    'generate_number_parts' => true,
                    'catenate_all' => true,
                    'preserve_original' => true,
                    'catenate_numbers' => true,
                ]
            ],
            'analyzer' => [
                'default' => [
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'char_filter' => [
                        'html_strip',
                        'replace',
                    ],
                    'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                    'filter' => [
                        'lowercase',
                        'word_delimiter',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
        'id' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        )
    );

    function getIndexName()
    {
        return 'get_product_name';
    }
```

**config/elasticquent.php**

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Elasticsearch Client Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array will be passed to the Elasticsearch client.
    | See configuration options here:
    |
    | http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html
    */

    'config' => [
        'hosts'     => ['localhost:9200'],
        'retries'   => 1,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Index Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the index name that Elasticquent will use for all
    | Elasticquent models.
    */

    'default_index' => 'get_product_name',

);
```

I'm using my Windows terminal in running their images in docker. Can someone help me figure this out? Found no luck around the net in getting some ideas.

Comment: someone has an idea on this?

Comment: Check if you're running a firewall like eg. ufw on your ES server. Sometimes people use a dynamic IP adress while accesisng an es cluster. Than you have to check your ufw rules on the ES server.  Are those rules still compliant with an IP adress if it's dynamic and has changed recently